# using docker for win10 to build image, and found the COPY command changed the new line

Tags: git, docker

in container,

```
# git diff selenium60.sh
diff --git a/selenium60.sh b/selenium60.sh
index 6ce5f9f..8893fb3 100644
--- a/selenium60.sh
+++ b/selenium60.sh
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
-#!/bin/sh
+#!/bin/sh^M
 java -Dphantomjs.binary.path=vendor/bin/phantomjs  -Dwebdriver.firefox.profile=default -Dwebdriver.reap_profile=true -jar vendor/bin/selenium-standalone.jar -timeout 60 -browserTimeout 60
\ No newline at end of file
```

i need to use git pull to update my source code, so how to make docker do not change the source code new line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're running `git pull` on the host and then `COPY` in the Dockerfile, the file endings have already been converted by Git - the `COPY` instruction does just that, Docker doesn't change the contents.

Easiest fix is to tell Git not to change the line endings, by adding the `--config core.autocrlf=input` option to your `git pull` command, which doesn't convert Unix-style line feeds.

Alternatively you can clone the repo inside the image as part of the build with `RUN git clone...`, which means you're cloning using Linux so Git will leave the line feeds alone.

Or you can add the `dos2linux` command in your build, run it to replace the `CRLF` line endings with `LF` and later remove the utility:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix
COPY ...
RUN dos2unix ...
```

The last option, and the Windows vs. Linux line-feed issue in docker has a nice write-up on [Will Anderson's blog](http://willi.am/blog/2016/08/11/docker-for-windows-dealing-with-windows-line-endings/).

Comment: I set the core.autocrlf=false and finally got it work.